# Why should front-end developers learn SASS where it won't be browser supported?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, frontend, twitter-bootstrap-4

bootstrap 4 picked up SASS where it won't be browser compatible language.. just to use bootstrap, developers gonna learn SASS ??
The image will explain why sass won't be browser supported

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers does not understand sass/scss/less, it can only understand css. Sass/scss is just a CSS pre-processor which **helps to reduce repetition** with CSS and **saves time**.

SASS/SCSS is more *stable and powerful* as it is an extension of CSS. It is easy for designers and developers to work *more efficiently and quickly*. It facilitates you to *write clean, easy and less CSS in a programming construct.*

But if you are using sass/scss, you need to pre-compile it which will generate some css code and then use those css into your project.

*You can use some **software like 'koala', 'liveroad', etc to compile your scss file to generate a new css file***. This software are very easy to use, I prefer 'koala'.

Answer (score 1):

SASS is a preprocessor and it will generate the clean, efficient css file. It does not matter whether it is running on browser or not, It is need to render the front end page. SASS is like easy way to write a css file.

Comment: Then i need to write sass for less / fast coding and then it should be converted to usual css, right?

Comment: And you get more features that are not in CSS. Specially for example variables. you just have to write SASS or LESS code and you can ask back-end developer to compile with SASS or LESS. It is more easy than writing CSS and maintaining it. Have a small try with SASS or LESS, you will be amazed.

Comment: thanks and I'll try it soon.. but I need to be more clear..  where should i write sass ? and from where i can convert it to css ? should i use any online site which provides this facilities ? cause still now, code editors do not support sass where editors help a developer a lot when writing css that need prefix , colors or some more

Comment: Babul Watch this whole video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GTBaQ2DcGUk

Answer (score 0):

SASS is a CSS preprocessor, meaning you write SASS that compiles to CSS. SASS is much easier to write and maintain than CSS which makes development faster and easier.

SASS is basically a template for CSS, you don't need SASS files for the live site to work, it is purely for development.

Comment: where should i write sass ? and from where i can convert it to css ? should i use any online site which provides this facilities ? cause still now, code editors do not support sass where editors help a developer a lot when writing css that need prefix , colors or some more

Comment: most modern IDEs supports SASS and LESS (E.g. Visual Studio Code). and  as front end developer, you don't have to compile it. you can ask your back end programmer to compile it. There are lot of compilers and just need to type one line of command. thats all if you want to compile yourself.

Comment: I use this for visual studio: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.WebCompiler